# efficient way to get byte[] from xml schema

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a complex object hierarchy data structure and its respective xml schema as well. Target is to get the byte[] in an efficient way. There are two ways for it

1. Load that xml as string and convert to byte[]
2. convert xml to c# object and then convert to byte[]

Which is the best approach and why.

Comment: You can't just convert an object to byte[] without first doing some serialization, which is what option #1 is.

Comment: So, what is schema or, at least the bit where the byte array resides?

Comment: check XmlSerializer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-7.0

Comment: Sounds like XY-problem. Describe the intended usage of that byte[] please?